# working with Ü in python

Tags: python, encoding

Hey guys im trying to work with Ü in python2.7 and it feels like hell

my file has # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- declared at the top

i have a list:

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
   'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Ä',
    'Ö', 'Ü']
```

and im trying to do this:

```
word = 'FÜNF'
new_string = ''
for letter in word:
    new_string += str(letters.index(letter))
```

i get a ValueError for letter not in string

and if i do

```
word = 'FÜNF'
for letter in word:
    print letter
```

what i get is:
F
├
£
N
F

can sbdy pls explain how to fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Soddin' Germans.. Nowt but trouble:)

Comment: I'm not sure of the fix, but it looks like when you iterate it is treating each byte as a character.

Comment: @Linuxios: My bad, Stack Overflow reformatted it so it looked wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is encoded in utf8. But you define a byte string, so your string has not 4 but 5 bytes, because Ü takes two bytes. To define a unicode string you have to type

```
word = u'FÜNF'
```

This is also the letters you see in your console. Probably your console cannot handle utf8.